# Web driver how to select option in DYNAMIC drop down in VBA

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have this HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<select name="calAlum" style="display: none;">undefined
<option value=""></option> 
<option value="5.0">5.0</option>
 <option value="5.1">5.1</option> 
<option value="5.2">5.2</option>
 <option value="5.3">5.3</option>
 <option value="5.4">5.4</option>
 <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
 <option value="5.6">5.6</option>
 <option value="5.7">5.7</option>
 <option value="5.8">5.8</option>
 <option value="5.9">5.9</option>
 <option value="6.0">6.0</option>
 <option value="6.1">6.1</option>
 <option value="6.2">6.2</option>
 <option value="6.3">6.3</option>
 <option value="6.4">6.4</option>
 <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
 <option value="6.6">6.6</option>
 <option value="6.7">6.7</option>
 <option value="6.8">6.8</option>
 <option value="6.9">6.9</option>
 <option value="7.0">7.0</option>
 <option value="7.1">7.1</option>
 <option value="7.2">7.2</option>
 <option value="7.3">7.3</option>
 <option value="7.4">7.4</option>
 <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
 <option value="7.6">7.6</option>
 <option value="7.7">7.7</option>
 <option value="7.8">7.8</option>
 <option value="7.9">7.9</option>
 <option value="8.0">8.0</option>
 <option value="8.1">8.1</option>
 <option value="8.2">8.2</option>
 <option value="8.3">8.3</option>
 <option value="8.4">8.4</option>
 <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
 <option value="8.6">8.6</option>
 <option value="8.7">8.7</option>
 <option value="8.8">8.8</option>
 <option value="8.9">8.9</option>
 <option value="9.0">9.0</option>
 <option value="9.1">9.1</option>
 <option value="9.2">9.2</option>
 <option value="9.3">9.3</option>
 <option value="9.4">9.4</option>
 <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
 <option value="9.6">9.6</option>
 <option value="9.7">9.7</option>
 <option value="9.8">9.8</option>
 <option value="9.9">9.9</option>
 <option value="10.0">10.0</option>
 </select>
```

when i click on the objetc display all the list but if a press "5" for example the list show only "5.0", "5.1" ,"5.2" etc. and when i press 5.8 only show me "5.8" llike valu to select

So i want to select any option with VBA, (whith other combox i dont have problems but with this have error)

i have tried this

```
sub CALF()

Dim H As selenium.Keys

*Here  find the element "select" whit the name "calAlum"* i dont have problem

For Each element In WEB3.FindElementsByTag("select")

If element.Attribute("name") = "calAlum" Then

 element.AsSelect.selectbyvalue Activecell *in this part show error*

End If

Next

MsgBox "fin"

End Sub
```

but for this drop down doesnt work i tried to use diferent ways but dont work, NOTE: this code go to inside IF

"to focus the box but dont work"

```
element.click
```

"to write value dont work"

```
element.sendkeys "5.8"
```

"to copy value in clipboard then paste value in the objetc dont work"

```
WEB3.SetClipBoard ActiveCell.Value
element.SendKeys Control, "V"
```

but if manually select any value in the object like "9.8" and the in the code use

```
R= element.value
```

or

```
R=elment.attrribute("value")
```

return "9.8" then i use

```
element.asselect.selectbyvalue R  work
```

but if i change R= "9.7" and use

```
element.asselect.selectbyvalue R
```

return Error value no found

then i tried after to wrap webelement in selectelemnet this

```
r= element.SelectedOption

r= element.asselect.selectedoption
```

to know what option is selected, but both return void "" obviusly is rare because  R= element.value return "9.8" then i use

```
element.asselect.options

for i=0 to element.asselect.options

r(i)=element.asselect.selectedoption

next
```

to know all option are in selectelement "element"  but return error its necesary a object so use

```
r = element.IsSelected
```

but return false thats to say i cant use the object like webelement and if i wrap to selectelment the object dont have any option, someone can help me.

If you help me how to select the object o how to manipulate object "select" dynamic

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

You can use a CSS selector to target the option of choice and then `.Click` to select. You extract the option value into a variable which you concatenate into the CSS selector string.

**Your example:**

For your example, you can use selector  `select option[value='5.0']`, where 5.0 is extracted into a variable.

[image: CSS query]

```
CONST SELECTED_INDEX As String = "5.0"
WEB3.FindElementByCss("select option[value='" & SELECTED_INDEX & "']").Click
```

---

Here is an example using Facebook and selecting the drop down day for birthday.

CSS selector for Facebook birthday day:

```
#day option[value='18']
```

[image: CSS query]

This reads as element with id `"day"`, containing tag `option`, with attribute `value` that is `=18`. `#` is id selector and `[]` is for attribute.

---

```
VBA Code:

Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.facebook.com/"
    Const SELECTED_INDEX As Long = 18
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        'Selector was e.g. for day 1 "#day option[value='1']"
        .FindElementByCss("#day option[value='" & SELECTED_INDEX & "']").Click

        Stop '<= Delete me later
        .Quit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

---